# Confirm process start in C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 projects created in C# using VS 2010.Project "Y" is the WCF service having operation contracts defined.Project "X" accesses methods of "Y" . Now I have code to start WCF service in project "X".
 Now before accessing first method from WCF service I want to make sure it has started properly.This service is just a executable.

How can I make sure executable is started properly?

Answer (score 2):

What you're interested in is presumably whether the WCF service is genuinely up and running - not just whether the process is started. So I would find some way of checking *that* in a cheap and side-effect-free way. For example, you could potentially fetch the WSDL if it's a SOAP service, or even add an "is everything healthy?" service call.

You can check for the process itself using [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) if you really want - but personally I'd at least *start* with the service call, and maybe try to find the process for added diagnostics if the service appears not to be up.

Comment: I am looking for those call only.Can you suggest some of methods() , who would do this for me.

Comment: @Rahul: I don't know what you mean by "I am looking for those call only." If you've added a no-op health-check method to your WCF service, just access that as you would any other service method.

Comment: The "is everything healthy?" service call is always a good way to go, given that something on the background (like the sql server) could be down and checking for the wsdl won't show that, plus you could return a more detailed response if required (making sure this is not going to cause any security issues)

Comment: I am not having "Is everything healthy?" calls in service.So I will need to query it from outside that executanel for service is Up and running fine.i want to achieve something like - Waitforsingleobject of C++

Comment: @Rahul: But don't you control this service? Can't you *add* such a call? If not, isn't there anything you can fetch (such as WSDL) to indicate that the service is up? There's the equivalent of WaitForSingleObject in .NET, but only when something exposes the appropriate API..

Comment: I am controlling the serive ,I can add calls but ehile trying to access very first call sometime I get exception as the service has faulted.i think this is due to service start is not clean or service is not up and running fine. So I want to make sure before actually accessing any methods in it verify it is un and running healthy.Any thoughts?

Comment: @Rahul: What are you afraid will happen if you just repeatedly call the no-op method, catching the exception (as it's somewhat expected)? Just call it with a delay between each attempt... it's easier to only need to worry about one thing, and the service isn't really *useful* until you can make that call anyway.